# 12V power supply for Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi

I want a small Raspberry Pi computer running off grid with a 12V, 35Ah battery and a solar panel. The current power supply converts AC to DC 12V, 1A, 12W. My question is if I cut the leads of the AC to DC converter and hook it up directly to a 12V battery will it run safely even with the voltage fluctuation of a charging/ discharging battery?

Comment: What Rpi do you have that gets 12V power without a intermediate 12v to 5v supply?

Comment: Buy a car cigarette lighter charger and power the Pi from that...

Answer (score 1):

First of all an off the shelf Raspberry Pi runs off of 5V, 12V will kill it. I am assuming you have a device that uses a Raspberry Pi and runs off of 12V and has an internal power converter.

The answer is yes, if your adapter provides 12V and you connect the device to a 12V supply that can provide the same or more current then it should run just as well as with the 12V adapter with a few possible issues.

First your power source may be more noisy than the adapter. If you have motors or other devices on the same power source or if it is not designed for sensitive electronics then it might not be as stable as the original adapter and you may experience issues.

Secondly "12V" battery powered systems are not necessarily 12V. Lead acid batteries can be up to 12.6V. Also depending on how it is being charged it can be significantly higher. A car for example might go as high as 14.7V when the engine is running.

Whatever is turning this 12V adapter's input into the 5V that the Raspberry Pi needs might be able to handle these issues. But it is not certain that is it will.